# web scraping with python, with navigation controller

Tags: python, web-scraping, sas, report

I am new to python and I need help with web scraping code to save a dynamic map every week. 
This is the [site](https://gis.cdc.gov/grasp/fluview/main.html) I am interested in.
The purpose is to get to the page, select season, select week, and download image to a local folder. I'll use the image to integrate for an automated weekly report using SAS.

thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: I need help with the code...so i can run it on spyder to save the .png file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should provide some kind of code example showing where exactly you are having problems.  Without that you are unlikely to receive any help here.

Comment: I have this questions answered. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
 from selenium import webdriver
import arrow

BASE_URL = 'https://gis.cdc.gov/grasp/fluview/main.html'
DOWNLOAD_PATH = "/Users/"

def closeWebDriver(driver):

    if os.name == 'nt':
        driver.quit()
    else:
        driver.close()

def getImage():

    profile = FirefoxProfile()

    profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","image/png")
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/png")
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", DOWNLOAD_PATH)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

    driver.get(BASE_URL)

    time.sleep(5)

    if not isValidTimeFrame(driver):
        print('Not the time to download yet!')
        closeWebDriver(driver)
        return

    selectFirstWeek(driver)

    print('- Consume the web.')
    wrapper = driver.find_element_by_class_name('downloads-help-area')

    download_img_els = wrapper.find_elements_by_class_name('downloads-button')

    for el in download_img_els:
        text = el.text.encode('utf-8')
#        print(text)
        if 'download image' == text.strip().lower():
            # Process
            downloadImage(el)
            break

    time.sleep(5)
    closeWebDriver(driver)


def isValidTimeFrame(driver):
    seasons_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('seasons-button')
    time_frame = seasons_button.text.encode('utf-8').strip().lower()
    current_year = arrow.now().to('local')
    current_year_str = current_year.format('YYYY')
    next_year = current_year.shift(years=1)
    next_year_str = next_year.format('YY')
    print(time_frame)
    compare_year = '%s-%s' % (current_year_str, next_year_str)

    return time_frame == compare_year

def selectFirstWeek(driver):
    prev = driver.find_element_by_id('prevMap')
    week = driver.find_element_by_id('weekSlider')

    while True:
        print(week)
        current_number = week.get_property('value')
        print('- Week: ' + current_number)
        prev.click()
        if int(current_number) < 2:
            break;

    time.sleep(1)


def downloadImage(el):
    print('- Click on ' + el.text)
    el.click()


getImage()
```